# Android title or Android action bar went missing while using "Extends Activity"

Tags: android, android-activity

Anyone know why my action bar/ my android title bar is missing when I extends Activity? All this while it is working fine and the action bar/ title activity is being shown on the activity whenever I used extend activity. I have been using extend activity for a very long time, but today when I click on create new Project to create a new android activity and extends activity, the action bar/ android title went missing. I have been searching for quite some time now and still unable to find the reason that causes this. How to fix this?

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: To Show ActionBar you have to extends your class with `AppcompatActivity` as `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated now. Activity is used for simple Activity without titlebar and actionabar

Comment: you have to extend ActionBarActivity for actionbar

Comment: But all this while I have been extending Activity instead of ActionBarActivity and it is working fine, until now T.T

Comment: And this example http://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/04/android-common-menu-options.html also only extends Activity, and the actionbar / title is shown in the activity

Comment: Since ActionBarActivity is depreciated, what should I use instead? because I only encounter this today and all these while I have been using Activity instead. Any way I can display the actionbar or the title ?

Comment: try one thing put title in menifest where you define activity. it may show title bar.

Comment: Hi, ty for the suggestion. I tried, but no luck T.T

Comment: try out with toolbar to show actionbar after lollipop release it is good practice with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shvet already pointed out the fastest fix would be to use `AppcompatActivity` as base class, since this class adds the *new* `Toolbar` by default.

The reason why you don't see the `ActionBar` is that it is hidden by default in the compat style. So you would need to change the style to something different in your manifest. But I would suggest you to use the compat library. That makes the compatibility much more easy.

Comment: Hi, but I am using  the following as usual? I did not change anything. Is it because now the android stuff have changed due to the new version updated etc ?<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

Comment: If you create a new app the compatibility framework is automatically added. If you click on that `@style/AppTheme` you will see that this style extends from the compatibility style, which has the rule useActionBar false

Comment: @AuroraBlaze As google will keep changing styles with new features, we have to change our coding too.

Comment: @Shvet, by the way, when google keep changing styles, will our SDK/ eclipse ADT auto update ? or we have to manually update to implement the new stuff? because I still don't seem to understand what had caused this to happen when I dont remember I had made any updates.

Comment: when google updates we can see new updates in our sdk and we have to download it.

Comment: @Shvet, ah I see, by the way. What about the FragmentActivity? the toolbar is also hidden? Because I have another activity that extends FragmentActivity, but also the same issues?

Comment: That depends if you use the compat library version or not :-)

Comment: @rekire, the compact library , do you mean the "app_compactv7" library? I am using it , but my FragmentActivity still don't show the action bar

Comment: Yes I do, when you use the compat library you also need to use the classes from the `android.support.v4.app` namespace and not from the `android.app` namespace.

Comment: Is there something like the "Extends AppCompactActivity" for FragmentActivity as well?

Comment: @AuroraBlaze if I don't miss something you can use there `AppCompactActivity` too.

Comment: I don't quite understand " if I don't miss something you can use there AppCompactActivity too" does that mean that it can be used as Fragment as well?>

Comment: Yes use for all activities the base class `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: wooo, cool. okiedokie~ rekire & @shvet, thank you very much for all those explanations. I appreciate it. Now I have a better understanding of what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

ActionBar is deprecated ever since Toolbar was introduced. Toolbar can be seen as a 'superset' of any action bar. So the 'old' ActionBar is now an example of a Toolbar. If you want similar functionality, but without deprecation warnings do the following:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

You need to define the Toolbar in your 'layout.xml' file like so:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

With this new functionality you can create your own custom ActionBar and let Android do the heavy lifting. Just create your own custom view that extends from Toolbar

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the suggestion. I appreciate it. I will try it out., by the way. Using this method will also mean that I will have to add in the "toolbar" everytime I create a new activity right?

Answer (score 0):

Simple change your extends Activity to ActionBarActivity and use ActionBar class you will get action bar from your activity.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I would not want to use "Extends ActionBarActivity" if I can because it had been deprecated.